# c - optimizing repetitive if else

Tags: c, if-statement, optimization

I have the following code:

```
if (a1 < a2)
   a3=0;
else
   a3=a1-a2;

if (b1 < b2)
   b3=0;
else
   b3=b1-b2;

if (c1 < c2)
   c3=0;
else
   c3=c1-c2;
```

The code is quite repetitive. Any suggestions on optimize code size? I do not want to use array.

Comment: Optimize what? Speed? Binary size?  Code size? Readability?

Comment: @EugeneSh. optimize code size

Comment: Looks like you might want *unsigned saturation*?

Comment: Ever heared about functions? "I do not want to use array." - You can't eat the cake and have it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a macro like:

```
#define COM(x,y) ((x<y)?0:(x-y))

...
a3 = COM(a1,a2);
b3 = COM(b1,b2);
c3 = COM(c1,c2);
```

or use a function instead.

```
int func(int x, int y)
{
   return (x<y)?0:(x-y);
}

a3 = func(a1,a2);
b3 = func(b1,b2);
c3 = func(c1,c2);
```

If you can use an array (for storing a, b, and c etc) for storing these values, then you can use a simple loop instead of repeating the macro/function call.

Comment: macro is the ideal solution for me here! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Macros are useful but be aware of [their pitfalls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html) too!

Comment: Never use a macro where a function will do!

Comment: The compiler's optimizer may automatically inline such a simple function. If not, `inline` [or `static inline`, if necessary] can be added to its definition. Then, it will make it just as fast/compact as the macro, but with the extra safety of the function. The function approach has the advantage that arguments are evaluated _once_. This helps in the general case of `COM(a1,calc())` where `calc` does heavy calculation or has side effects.

Comment: I have answered with the option to use a function as well and warned OP about the pitfalls of macros in my comment. Macros themselves are not bad; rather using it in complex expressions or using it with side effects is the problem. So, downvoting this seems excessive to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @usr. I understand the pitfalls of using macro and as Craig-esty pointed out, functions are a safer solution. For the specific issue I am dealing, macro is best-suited. It may not be the same for someone else!

Answer (score 1):

you can start off by initializing the variables first then just use if statements if needed. For example.

```
a3=a1-a2;
b3=b1-b2;
c3=c1-c2;

if(a1<a2)
  a3=0;

if(b1<b2)
  b3=0;

if(c1<c2)
  c3=0;
```